# npm install exits with: node -e 'process.exit(0)'

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, node-modules

I'm stumped on this one. When I run `npm install` in my app directory, and after running for about a minute, it exits.  Nothing gets installed in node_modules.  It seems to be failing at different points in the process, but always with the same error.

On exit, it logs this:

```
v8-profiler@5.6.5 preinstall /home/ec2-user/segue4/node_modules/.staging

node -e 'process.exit(0)'
```

Possibly relevant info:

- My npm came with node, and I installed node using `nvm`. The version is the `stable` version (node: v6.2.0, npm: 3.9.5).
- This is all happening on an ec2.  So there's the possibility of a network issue that I've overlooked.  However- if I individually install a node_module locally (ie. `npm install mongoose`) it works perfectly fine, so I've sort of ruled that out.

When I run `npm install --verbose`, I don't seem to get any more insight.  That same log message, preceded by nothing unusual.  But like I said, it seems to happen at different points when I run it different times.

I'm wondering if it's a bad package or if it's an issue with npm itself.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "description": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "meanjs-version": "x.x.x",
  "private": false,
  "author": "xxxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.28",
    "npm": ">=1.4.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acl": "~0.4.4",
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "cfenv": "~1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.8.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "file-stream-rotator": "~0.0.6",
    "forever": "~0.14.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.13",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.3",
    "mocha": "~1.20.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.3",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "multer": "~1.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "phantomjs": ">=1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "validator": "^3.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coveralls": "^2.11.4",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-eslint": "~17.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-mocha-istanbul": "^2.4.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "~0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-node-inspector": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-protractor-coverage": "~0.2.15",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csslint": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-cssmin": "~0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-karma": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "karma": "~0.12.37",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.4.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "mock-fs": "~3.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "should": "^7.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue myself. The VM I was running `npm install` on ran out of RAM. After increasing the memory, the command executed successfully.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  This seemingly resolved itself on mine.  Was never quite sure what happened, but this makes perfect sense.